# Not Recognized User Control in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I am using `Windows Forms`, language - `C#`. I have a Project `Calculator`. I added a `UserControl` to that project `ButtonC`. I dragged that `Control` to my Form, and when running it, I am getting an error that `ButtonC` in does not exist.

[image: Control Not Recognized]
Can't understand what is the problem. But When I manage that line like this

```
this.ButtonC = new ButtonC();
```

That does not give any error, but every time, before running I have to change that, and I don't think that it is the right solution. Thanks for Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that your `ButtonC` and your `Calculator` is in different namespace. Change them to the same namespace may solve the problem.

**Edit:**

I think I understand the problem. This should be a "bug" of auto-generated designer code. They simply put your namespace before your control, in your case it's "Calculator". But within the code, your namespace and your class are the same, thus the compiler interprets wrongly: it thinks Calculator.ButtonC is a subclass within Class Calculator.

If I'm not wrong, simply make your Namespace and your Class Name different may do the job.

Comment: actually the Namespace is the same - Calculator

Comment: It seems that your designer treats the control as a Class within Calculator.Calculator, but actually it's within Calculator. Just remove the preceded Calculator, like what you mentioned in your post may do the job.

Comment: Yes, it works that way, but every time before after runing one time I have to remove that Calculator again and again :/

Comment: I think I understand the problem. This should be a "bug" of auto-generated designer code. They simply put your namespace before your control, in your case it's "Calculator". But within the code, your namespace and your class are the same, thus the compiler interprets wrongly: it thinks Calculator.ButtonC is a subclass within Class Calculator.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, simply change your Namespace or Class name to something else, i.e. make these two different, may do the job.

Comment: my Thanks to you :) I was struggling with this for two hours :D Thanks @nevets :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59446/discussion-between-nevets-and-romo-daneghyan).